# Does GPS receiver use spheres or hyperboloids to solver for position?

Tags: gps

I've found in many articles that GPS devices use the spheres theory to get the its position, but sometimes I read that these devices solve for time differences between satellites transmissions, using hyperboloids.

I want to understand which one is correct?

Comment: related https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/163942/in-hyperbola-model-of-how-gps-equations-are-solved-why-do-3-satellites-give-onl

Answer (score 1):

They use both.
Spheres are around each satellite.
The intersection of 2 spheres (from 2 satellites) with a certain difference in radius results in a hyperboloid.
3 satellites result in 3 spheres, 2 hyperboloids that result in a curved line.
4 satellites result in 4 spheres, 3 hyperboloids, 2 curved lines and when those 2 lines intersect you get a point = your position!
All signals received and calculated by a small gadget in microseconds.